# PHP ->mysql getting wrong encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I tried to connect to mysql database and to get string in **UTF-8**.

```
       <?php 
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");
        mysql_set_charset('utf-8');
        mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
        mysql_query('set character set utf8');
```

However the code below responds  me that that the string that i get from db is encoded in **ASCII** .

```
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tweet");
        $content =array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                     $content[] =$row['content'];
         }
        echo mb_detect_encoding($content[0]);//this line prints: ASCII
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

Using code below i get all turkish characters except **'ğ','ş','ı'**.

```
 $current_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($content[0], 'auto');
 for($x=0;$x<sizeof($content);$x++){
    $content[$x] = iconv($current_encoding, 'UTF-8', $content[$x]);}
 echo mb_detect_encoding($content[0]);//this line again prints: ASCII
```

How can i get strings from db encoded in **UTF-8**?

Comment: actually `mb_detect_encoding` is wrong function to use at all, it tries to guess encoding, so don't rely on its return, just output your content to HTML with utf8 encoding and open in browser - you will see that everything is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use `mysqli_connect` to connect to database, you need to use:

```
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf-8');
```

and not

```
mysql_set_charset('utf-8');
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
mysql_query('set character set utf8');
```

just after connecting to database. You will then no need to use any mb_detect_encoding or iconv functions because assuming data was inserted correctly, you will also get correct result.

You should also make sure, that your table/fields have set utf8 encoding for example `utf8_encode_ci`